# How to add in auto play audio option?

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio

how to add in auto play audio option, whereby it will beep (short beep) once at the start of “Observe”, “Snapshot”, “Record”, in different tones of beeps? it will have different color background when the word changes.--- image click here --->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di3B9.png)

Comment: You need to make a raw folder inside res and store your .mp3 files in it.Then use MediaPlayer classes create, start, release etc methods.

Comment: got it thank you so much! @anup

Comment: your welcome @itnotsopro